# Select tag on submit alert something

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi please visit this fiddle 1st: [http://jsfiddle.net/UWNtK/20/](http://jsfiddle.net/asif097/UWNtK/20/)

When this dropdown (select tag) changes from the default value into numbers (example: from category1 to 3) and then on click on the submit button, I want to `alert()` something. What is the jquery method for it?

Here is the html structure:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<div class="drop1">
    <select>
        <option value="categ1">Category1</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="drop2">
    <select>
        <option value="categ2">Category2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
    <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

N.B: I am new to jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**change()**](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method here:

```
$("select").change(function () {
  alert(this.value);
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function () {
   var $select1 = $(".drop1 select");
   var $select2 = $(".drop2 select");
   if ($select1.val() !== 'categ1') alert($select1.val());
   else if ($select2.val() !== 'categ2') alert($select2.val());
});
```

Comment: I have made some changes in my question, please read it again, thanks

Comment: But, it's always alerting the the 1st dropdown `val()`

Comment: If you change both the dropdown, then only the 1st dropdown `val()` is alerting

Comment: What do you want? if you want both the alerts than just remove the else if, and keep it just if, and try again..

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select').change( function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Would be an option. 
See <kbd>[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/UWNtK/19/)</kbd>

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) if you want to see the docu.

**EDIT**

updated <kbd>[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/UWNtK/23/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type="button"]').click(function () {
        var selectOne = $('.drop1 select');
        var selectTwo = $('.drop2 select');
        if (selectOne.val() != 'categ1') {
            alert(selectOne.val());
        }
        if (selectTwo.val() != 'categ2') {
            alert(selectTwo.val());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have made some changes in my question, please read it again, thanks

Comment: Updated my fiddle. I'd rather suggest you to give your selects an unique ID or something...but that depends on what you want to achieve.